# Is there a way to add a new drive to the windows software raid 5 volume?

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, software-raid, windows, raid5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expand Windows Server 2008 RAID 5 array](https://serverfault.com/questions/18361/expand-windows-server-2008-raid-5-array)

Hello there!

Is there any way to extend my Windows Server 2008 R2 software RAID5 volume by another drive or am I bound to recreate that volume from scratch?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Whether or not it is possible (I'm not sure), I'd get a full backup before I start. Then the question is redundant, and all you lose is time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already asked this [question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/18361/expand-windows-server-2008-raid-5-array) - short answer, no, it can't be done safely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with Windows software RAID but you could take the guesswork out of it with a little no-risk experimentation. Create a virtual machine with a bunch of virtual drives. Create a RAID 5 array and then see what happens if you try to add another drive.